# Asp.Net Core RazorPages AuthorizeFolder with an exceptional page

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, razor-pages

In RazorPagesOptions in asp.net core 3,

I authorized a folder `FolderA` with policy `PolicyA` like below.

```
options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/FolderA", "PolicyA");
```

But I want to apply an exceptional policy `PolicyB` to a page `PageB` under `FolderA`, 
so that users who entitled `PolicyB` but not entitled `PolicyA` can access `PageB` 
while cannot access the other pages under `FolderA`.

I tried to add a page authorization like below

```
options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/FolderA/PageB", "PolicyB");
```

but, it does not allow users who entitled `PolicyB` without `PolicyA` to access the the `PageB`.

Is there a way to give a policy exception to a specific page under a authorized folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, you can dynamically check the path in policy to allow the specific page . For example :

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{

    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/FolderA", "PolicyA");

});
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("PolicyA", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
        {
            var resource = context.Resource.ToString();

            if (resource.Equals("/FolderA/PageB"))
            {
                return true;
            }                
            return false;                
        });
    });
});
```

So that any request to FolderA will fire the policy , you can then add your custom logic in policy , for example , check user claim from `context.User.Claims` .